# How to ask people to speak slowly so they really speak slowly?

Tags: listening, indian-english

I'm learning English for many years, and I use English at work. Some clients I cannot understand. I ask them to speak slowly. They do, but then they speak quickly again. My bigger problem is talking to French or Indian clients. Did you face this situation and find a solution?

Comment: *The polite way of asking them to speak slowly* is probably a better question for [interpersonal.se]

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, "What is the correct English you should use to ask someone to speak more slowly?" Then the problem is that the *English* is easy, but the * politics* is difficult.

"Please speak slowly and clearly, I am not a native English speaker and I want to make sure I correctly understand you."

Everything after that is politics.

Comment: What do you mean by "politics"? Do you mean "interpersonal skills"?

Comment: I mean that it is easy to cause offense or to have people look down on you if you use the wrong words, even if they are correct in English.